# Python Excel Pandas Loop won't break

Tags: python, excel, pandas, loops

I have been reading a bunch here on Stack Overflow and cannot figure out why my program loop won't break.

I tried many different iterations of the break, in the top loop, inside the second loop, it just won't stop reading. This program looks at a file and I have set the index on ['Group_Number']. It looks at the group number, does a groupby and sets up a draft with attachment. There are about 194 rows in the excel file with addresses.

Everything works- but the loop doesn't end. Also, it skips the first line which I need it to read.

Please be kind I am a new programmer and have been trying to fix this on my own for about a week.

```py
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client as win32

# function to remove all consecutive duplicates
# from the string in Python


# read the latest excel file and break it up by group number,
# list groups with members in a separate HTML
# file to be emailed out later.
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)
pd.set_option("display.width", None)
pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth", None)

# Column Names Set UP
dtypes = {
    "Group_Number": "category",
    "Group_Name": "category",
    "Process_Owner": "category",
    "Email_Address": "category",
    "MESSAGING_ID": "category",
    "NAME": "category",
    "Files": "category",
}
# create a dataframe for the loop to read
df = pd.read_excel(
    r"C:\Users\aross9\Desktop\outFile\Madison Working folder\Dropped.xlsx",
    dtype=dtypes,
    usecols=list(dtypes)
    + [
        "Group_Number",
        "Group_Name",
        "Process_Owner",
        "Email_Address",
        "MESSAGING_ID",
        "NAME",
        "Files",
    ],
)

names = df["Group_Number"]
owner = df["Process_Owner"]
emails = df["Email_Address"]
attachments = df["Files"]
PATH = r"C:\Users\aross9\Desktop\outFile\Madison Working folder"

row_count = 0
col_count = 0

index = df.set_index(["Group_Number"])


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index == " ":
        break
    else:
        try:
            for x, row in df.groupby(names):
                # send emails in drafts
                outlook = win32.Dispatch("outlook.application")
                mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
                mail.To = emails[x]
                mail.Subject = "Message subject group"
                attachment = attachments[x]
                with open(attachment, "r") as my_attachment:
                    myfile = my_attachment.read()
                    mail.HTMLBODY = (
                        "<b>Please Find information about your Group here:</b> <br><br>"
                        + myfile
                    )
                    mail.Save()
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
            continue
```

Comment: your code sample is too complicated for the question that you're trying to ask.  Essentially, you're only asking why the loop doesn't break.  I'd say the first check should be: ```sum(df.index == ' ')```.  If this prints 0, you don't have a blank space index in your dataframe

Comment: Please fix your indentation and consider reducing your code. Also please include a sample of `df`.

Comment: Thanks. giving it a try. Like I said I am a new programmer still learning.

Comment: Regarding the problem that the first row is not read. If in the first row are not the column names you have to add `header=None`  to `read_excel()`. Then the first row is read like every other row.

Comment: I do have a first row with headers, it is skipping the row after it and going to the 3rd. I should have specified that

Comment: Group_Number Group_Name Process_Owner Email_Address MESSAGING_ID NAME Files
1 MERT Team 1 (ACC - Nelson)   0001 MERT TEAM 1 DOCUMENTATION C:\Users\aross9\Desktop\outFile\Madison Working folder\group1.html
2 MERT Team 2 (West Hospital)   0002 MERT TEAM 2 DOCUMENTATION C:\Users\aross9\Desktop\outFile\Madison Working folder\group2.html
3 MERT Team 3 (Children's Pavilion)   0003 MERT TEAM 3 DOCUMENTATION C:\Users\aross9\Desktop\outFile\Madison Working folder\group3.html
4 Code Blue Alert   0004 CODE BLUE DOCUMENTATION C:\Users\aross9\Desktop\outFile\Madison Working folder\group4.html

Comment: Can someone tell me how to upload the excel file to the comments?

Comment: @AcrRca you can edit your question to add it in the question (more readable). At the bottom of your question there are `Share Edit Follow...`  so click on edit and add the data in the question :) I think the best would be to add in the question the result of `print(df.head().to_dict())` you can't upload a excel file directly

Comment: Just guessing, but maybe the problem is caused by having an unnecessary nested loop, i. e. iterating over the "static" result of `df.groupby()` for every single row returned from `df.iterrows()`? Anyway, as others wrote, I would also recommend following the [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) practice, so that people can help you here.

Comment: Thanks, I am home now, I will do so in the morning.

Comment: ``for index, row in df.iterrows():
        ##send emails in drafts
        outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
        mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
        mail.To = emails[index]
        mail.Subject = 'Message subject group'
        attachment = attachments[index]
        with open(attachment, 'r') as my_attachment:
               myfile = my_attachment.read()
               mail.HTMLBODY = "<b>Please Find information about your Group here:</b> <br><br>" + myfile
               mail.Save() ``` Thank you Petr, you were completely correct, rem groupby and now it works.